# Not all code paths return a value in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I cant seem to figure out why my `[HttpPost]Index()` method is giving me an error message stating that

> not all code paths return a value

I tried putting `return View()` after the `AddModelError` but it still gives me that error message.

```
public class SnowboardController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SnowboardModel SbModel)
    {
        if (SbModel.DiscountSenior && SbModel.DiscountStudent)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Discounts", "Dude, you cannot take both student and senior discounts.");
        }
        //return to view if any fields invalid
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(SbModel);
        }
    }
}
```

I also added `@Html.ValidationMessage("Discounts")` in my view.

Comment: Because there is no `return` statement if neither of you `if` conditions return `false` Typically you would have code to save and redirect at the bottom of the method (`return RedirectToAction(...);`)

Answer (score 6):

In the Index method, all your returns are wrapped in ifs... you need a return at the end of the method.